# MYSQL PHP - Counting values more column WHERE id and DATE LAST 7 DAYS

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

i have issue.
I need counting more columns where id and date.
date must not be older than 7 days (1 week)

In the picture, we see the ID value as the first and the second value.

I need an SQL query to add the value 10 and 10 = 20 according to ID 344, for example

The same for the second ID. I'm tired already.
Thank you

[image: HERE IS IMAGE]

Comment: please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read also up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: also you have no date column in your sample. please read also about a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a date column to get data of last 7 days. So here is my answer after adding a 'date' column.

**Answer 1.** If you want sum of all the unique id's

```
select id, sum(object) as value, count(id) as count_of_id, from table_name WHERE date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY group by id
```

**Answer 2.** If you want sum of particular id

```
select id, sum(object) as value, count(id) as count_of_id, from table_name WHERE date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY and id = 344
```